# naming for group inputs and retrieving values in controllers in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table that its rows are created dynamically with jQuery. I can add or remove rows so when all fields are ready, I just submit it.
Since the rows are created before any posting, how can I properly name them to later easily retrieve their values in controller actions like Create? Consider that each row is "an object" or at least an array for each one.

In ruby, just by adding [] to the `name=` attribute do the job, not sure if ASP.NET is possible to that.

This is the script for creating rows:

```
function add_row() {
  var detalle = $('#detail');
  var index = $("#detail tbody").children("tr").length;
  var newRow = '<tr>' +
    '<td style="display:none"><input name="Detalle.Index" type="hidden" value="' + index + '" /></td>' +
    '<td data-title="Quantity">' +
    '<div class="input-group">' +
    '<span class="input-group-addon"></span>' +
    '<input class="form-control" type="number" aria-label="Quantity" name="Detail['+ index +'].quantity" id="Detail_' + index + '__quantity"  step="0.001" min="0.000">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td data-title="Price" >' +
    '<div class="input-group">' +
    '<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>' +
    '<input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Price" name="Detail['+ index +'].price" id="Detail_' + index + '__price" step="0.001" min="0.000" required="true">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td data-title=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="delete_row(this)">Cancel</button></td>' +
    '</tr>';
  detail.append(newRow);
}
```

In controller I can access to Request with `Request.Form["Detail[0].price"]` to get a specific value, however I'm not able how to get the total of rows to create a loop and get values like this: `Detail[i].inputname`

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `Request` Make use of the features of MVC. You POST method should include a parameter `List<yourModel> model` so that the collection is bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`. Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some examples

Comment: This is Master-detail scenario. That is still applicable?

Comment: Absolutely. And note in the examples the hidden input for the indexer (in your case it will be `<input type="hidden" name="Detail.Index" value="#" />` (where `#` is the indexer) which allows you to delete items from the collection. Note also your current implementation could never work because if your added some items and then deleted some, you could end up with duplicate indexers because of your use of `$("#detail tbody").children("tr").length;`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `Request.Form[".."]` to get the form values, make use of MVC's powerful model binding features and bind directly to your model.

Based on the code in your script you have a main model with a property named `Detail` which is a collection of a complex object with properties `quantity` and `price`, so your method can be

```
public ActionResult Edit(YourMainModel model)
```

and the values of `model.Detail` will be correctly bound.

However there a 2 errors in your script which will prevent binding to the model

First is the incorrect `name` attribute for the hidden input. It needs to be

```
<input name="Detail.Index" type="hidden" value="' + index + '" />
```

not `name="Detalle.Index"`

The second is that your indexer is based on the number of rows in the table which could result in duplicate indexers. If you started with an empty table and added 3 items, the last one would have the index value as `2`. If you then deleted say the first one and then added another, its index value would also be `2` causing binding to fail. You need to ensure that the indexer is unique. One way of achieving this is to use

```
var index = (new Date()).getTime();
```